# Please help transform the perspective of Sensation by Arthur Rimbaud from a male first person point of view to a female first person point of view

Tags: genre

Here's the original version of the poem Sensation by Arthur Rimbaud:

```
Par les soirs bleus d’été, j’irai dans les sentiers,
Picoté par les blés, fouler l’herbe menue :
Rêveur, j’en sentirai la fraîcheur à mes pieds.
Je laisserai le vent baigner ma tête nue.

Je ne parlerai pas, je ne penserai rien :
Mais l’amour infini me montera dans l’âme,
Et j’irai loin, bien loin, comme un bohémien,
Par la Nature, – heureux comme avec une femme.
```

It was written from a male perspective. Now I want to change it into female perspective, and here's what I came up with:

```
Par les soirs bleus d’été, j’irai dans les sentiers,
Picotée par les blés, fouler l’herbe menue :
Rêveuse, j’en sentirai la fraîcheur à mes pieds.
Je laisserai le vent baigner ma tête nue.

Je ne parlerai pas, je ne penserai rien :
Mais l’amour infini me montera dans l’âme,
Et j’irai loin, bien loin, comme une bohémienne,
Par la Nature, – heureuse comme avec une femme.
```

I've changed **Picoté** to **Picotée**, **Rêveur** to **Rêveuse**, **un bohémien** to **une bohémienne** and **heureux** to **heureuse**.

Did I miss something?

Thank you:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No error, but some of the verses and rimes now don't work anymore. But I don't know if this is enough to transform the perspective into a *female first person point of view*, since this may not be well defined. Don't know what to do with *comme avec une femme*, for example.

Comment: Thank you very much Frank for your prompt response! I did fail to notice the verses and rimes.

Comment: @Ray Also _comme avec une femme_. If the result should be perfectly symmetrical, it may need to change to _comme avec un homme_?

Comment: I would not touch "comme avec une femme". It's not directly related to the point of view, it would be heteronormative to change it.

Comment: @AloisChristen I don't think it's a question of heteronormativity. Not changing it means the text now suggests homosexuality, which is the opposite in the original. Having a prominent place as the last words of the poem, I think it is very relevant to the point of view. This is just to point out that this exercise is a bit pointless in general. Changing "perspectives" and "viewpoints" is not as simple as changing the agreement of the adjectives.

Comment: @Frank If the exercise is solely on grammar, "femme" has nothing to do with it and should not be changed. If the exercise is about a new perspective, saying it should be heterosexual because the last one was makes as much sense as saying it should be changed for the same reason. If it's because that's the last word of the poem, I'd argue that changing the sexual orientation of the narrator is less of a change than changing the poetic picture of "comme avec une femme" to "comme avec un homme". I admit the last point is subjective.

Comment: @AloisChristen I'm just pointing out that the exercise is quite subjective. In a poem, especially one by Rimbaud, changing the point of view from heterosexual to homosexual would not be neutral at all. Now, don't get me wrong: I don't have a strong opinion one way or the other, but I'm pointing out that it's not clear how much "perspective" and "point of view" should actually encompass, and that the whole exercise is very subjective beyond the obvious grammar changes. And some verses and rimes are damaged. Why do this to Rimbaud's original?

Comment: Today, there's no real reason you have to pronounce the 'e' at the end of *rêveuse* and *heureuse*. So the only real problem is *bohémienne*, which no longer rhymes with *rien*. But I don't see why you can't leave that as a male gender—it doesn't necessarily refer to the speaker, because the words are *comme un bohémien* (*like a gypsy*), and you can just take that as referring to a generic gypsy of either sex.

Comment: @PeterShor Even if you do that, you will have to take a stand on _comme avec une femme_ next, and changing that to _comme avec un homme_ would destroy the rhyme with _âme_, while leaving _comme avec une femme_ would induce strong suggestions of homosexuality, and that would be a perspective contrary to that of the original. It's hopeless.